# La excepción se lanza cuando no debe - C++

Tags: c++, clase, excepciones

En varias operaciones sobre un TAD ListaArray me sucede el mismo error, una de ellas es la siguiente, la función `resto`:

`lista_array.cpp`

```
template<typename E, int N>
void ListaArray<E,N>::resto(ListaArray<E,N>& resto)
{
    if (ultimo_ == N-1)
    {
    throw EMemoriaAgotada();
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=ultimo_;i++)
        {
            resto.almacen_[i-1]=almacen_[i];
        }
        resto.ultimo_=ultimo_-1;
    }
}
```

Como veis esta operación tiene un `throw EMemoriaAgotada`.
Pues **solo** me lanza`EListaVacia` introduciendo **cualquier** lista(**vacía o no**), .

Así están definidas las excepciones(dentro de la clase ListaArray(`lista_array.hpp`):

```
template<typename E, int N>//tipo E y el numero máximo del array
class ListaArray
{
public:
    //definicion de la excepcion EMemoriaAgotada
    class EMemoriaAgotada: public std::runtime_error
    {
    public:
      EMemoriaAgotada(const std::string& w = "EMemoriaAgotada"): std::runtime_error(w) {}
    };
    //definicion de la excepcion ElistaVacia
    class EListaVacia: public std::domain_error
    {
    public:
        EListaVacia(const std::string& w= "EListaVacia"): std::domain_error(w){}
    };
. . . . . . .
```

Así es la operación para probarla(`prueba.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista_array.hpp"

#define Elemento int
#define ListaPrueba ListaArray<Elemento, 10>
............
void probarResto(std::istream& is)
{
  ListaPrueba l;
  ListaPrueba r;

  is >> l;

  l.resto(r);
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
  std::cout << l;
}
.................
int main()
{
  char opcion;

 #define is std::cin
 #endif

  try
  {
      // Lectura de la operación a probar
      is >> opcion;

      switch(opcion)
      {
        case 'r': probarResto(is); break;
        case 'v': probarEsVacia(is); break;
        case 'l': probarLongitud(is); break;
        case 'i': probarInsertarFinal(is); break;
        case 'C': probarCopiar(is); break;
        case '=': probarIgual(is); break;
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& excepcion)
    {
      std::cout << "EXCEPCION GENERADA: "  <<  excepcion.what();
    }
  return 0;
}
```

¿Alguna idea de porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la función original, que daba problemas, como la excepción salía donde no debía, me recomendaron buscar los `throws`.

Función con un `throw` sobrante:

```
template<typename E, int N>
void ListaArray<E,N>::insertarFinal(E e)
{
    if (ultimo_ == N-1)
    {
    throw EMemoriaAgotada();
    }
    if(esVacia()){ throw EListaVacia();}
    else
    {
        ultimo_++;
        almacen_[ultimo_]=e;
    }
}
```

Quito el `throw` que me da problemas y arreglado:

```
template<typename E, int N>
void ListaArray<E,N>::insertarFinal(E e)
{
    if (ultimo_ == N-1)
    {
    throw EMemoriaAgotada();
    }
    else
    {
        ultimo_++;
        almacen_[ultimo_]=e;
    }
}
```